# The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

That quote is from the [man page of pthread_self()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self).

***So, on what basis should I decide whether I should use `pthread_self` or `gettid` to determine which thread is running the function?***

Both are non portable.
Why are there two different functions to get the thread ID?

Comment: Because Linux's threading is kludgy.

Comment: The [`pthread_self`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_self.html) function is very portable, the "P" in ["POSIX"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) stands for *Portable* after all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> So, on what basis should I decide whether I should use pthread_self or
>   gettid to determine which thread is running the function?

You should always use `pthread_self()` whenever you want to identify a thread within your application. `gettid()` *can be* used for certain purposes *and* if you know it's Linux. For example, `gettid()` can be used to get seed for a thread specific seed (used in `srand()`).

> Both are non portable.

This is not entirely true. `gettid()` is not portable as its a Linux specific function. But `pthread_self()` is portable as long as you don't make any assumptions about its representation.

For example, the following is *not* portable.

```
printf("Thread ID is: %ld", (long) pthread_self());
```

as there's no guarantee that whatever `pthread_self()` is going to be an integer of some sort. But

```
pthread_t my_tid; //filled elsewhere

pthread_t tid = pthread_self();

if( pthread_equal(my_tid, tid) ) {
   /* do stuff */
}
```

is fully portable.

The former is not portable because it *assumes* that thread id is an integer whereas the latter is not.

> Why are there two different functions to get the thread ID?

They are not two different ways to get the same value. One (`pthread_self()` is provided by the thread library (pthreads) while the other (`gettid()`is an OS-specific function. A different OS may provide a different interface/syscall to get thread ID similar to `gettid()`. So you can't rely on `gettid()` in a portable application.

Comment: As a minor remark, the cast to integer works also for `pthread_t` being a pointer type, which it actually is on many architectures. So `(long)` is probably not so good, but `(uintptr_t)` has good chances to work on almost all platforms nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. I printed the thread Id this way: `pthread_t tId = pthread_self ();
        qDebug () << "\nConsumer: " << tId;` and got "140482062563072". Can this huge number be valid, or I am missing some point?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius `pthread_t` is an opaque type. It could be a `long long` or `struct` pointer or any other type an implementation chooses to. What you see is probably an id or an address. You just can't rely on it. `gcc -E -P file.cpp | grep pthread_t` can be used to find what your implementation `typedef'`ed it to. But it can be different on other systems. If you need to store it use `pthread_t`, to compare use `pthread_equal()`. As Jens noted, you can cast it to `uintptr_t` to print so that it would work for both pointer types and integer types.

Answer (score 7):

`pthread_self() returns the process-wide unique pthread-id.`

gettid() returns the (pthread implementation specific) system-wide unique thread-id (on Linux).

```
the TID(thread id) returned by gettid() is unique inside a process
```

Yes.

```
(or inside a program with multiple processes,
```

Yes.

```
inside a process, different thread has different thread id.
```

Yes.

```
the TID returned by pthread_self() is unique across processes,
```

No.

```
different thread has different TID on the same machine at the same time.
```

Yes in the same process, No across the whole machine.

As gettid() is Linux specific and therefore not portable, the only way to system widely identify a pthread is to use its (system wide unique) parent process id as returned by getpid() along with its (process-wide unique) pthread-id as returned by pthread_self().

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting study in the difference between *conceptual* terminology and real *software entities* (which belong to specific software abstractions).

First of all, pay attention to the *types* of these two calls.

```
pid_t gettid(void);
pthread_t pthread_self(void);
```

One is `pid_t` and the other is `pthread_t`. Both of these refer to a common conceptual entity called a `thread`, but the different types imply that these are two different `software entities`. They are different representations of a `thread id`, and make sense within the software abstraction that incorporates it. So, `pthread_t` makes sense *only* within the abstraction supported by the `pthread` package, and `pid_t` makes sense within the abstraction that incorporates this type (i.e. Linux system calls that deal in `pid_t`).

You should be using the correct type based on the context. Use `pthread_t` in the context which requires the type `pthread_t` and `pid_t` in the context which requires `pid_t` - regardless of the fact that they might refer to the same thread.

Each one of these contexts have prescribed syntax for comparison and equality. `pid_t` can be directly compared by the `==` operator, while `pthread_t` must be compared by invoking `pthread_equal`.

The reason for this dual representation / software abstractions is that the `pthread` library is a portable thread library that can be implemented on different operating systems. Different implementations of the `pthread` library guarantee that the `thread id` type will always be `pthread_t`. These threads may underneath map to a operating system specific `thread entity` whose OS identifier depends on the operating system (e.g. for Linux it is `pid_t`; for Windows it is `DWORD`).

So, while the underlying implementation may differ from OS to OS, the code written against the `pthread` abstraction remains portable across OSes (as long as you confine yourself to the `pthread` abstraction).