# call pthread_self() from a single-threaded application

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pthreads

On Linux `ps -Lf` will display a thread ID in the column `LWP` and number of thread in `NLWP` column. Any single threaded process will have `PID` and `LWP` values the same.

What should `pthread_self()` return on a single threaded application? Initially I was expecting that its value should be the same as a process ID, executing this call, but results were different. Then I read `man pthread_self` and `man gettid` and learned that the value returned by `pthread_self()` is not the same as `gettid()` result.

So can I even trust `pthread_self()` output executed in a non-threaded environment (process)?

Comment: If you trust it in multi-threaded program, why not in a single threaded program? ;-)

Comment: @P.P OK, but how can I interpret pthread_t value then? It is deliberately made opaque and implementation specific, i.e. it could be integer or it could be wrapped in a `struct` etc. Does it mean that I should only use `gettid` if I need integer representation of thread ID?

Comment: You don't *interpret* it in anyway - that's the point of it being opaque. The `pthread_t` is assigned by pthreads library and outside of the process, it has no useful meaning. Think of it like names you might give to threads like "master", "worker", "timer", etc to threads. If you need *integer* representation, you can assign one yourself (e.g. map each `pthread_t` to an int or wrap in a struct: `struct mythreads { pthread_t tid; int tid;}`). Of course, you could use `gettid` too - but that's less portable because `gettid` is Linux-specific (pthreads library can be used on any POSIX systems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pthread_self](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_self.html) is defined to return the calling thread's ID regardless of whether the program
is multi-threaded or a single-threaded.

As you found, the return value of `pthread_self()` isn't same as the LWP in Linux (`gettid`) and as such it doesn't have any meaning outside of the process; `pthread_t` is
an opaque type. Related: [The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34370172/1275169)

Its utility is very limited as there's not much practical use for `pthread_t` in a single-threaded program. You can use in `pthread_setschedparam` for example.

But if you are asking whether returns any valid value in single-threaded program, then the answer is yes.